# Android custom ListView items (findViewById returns null)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-lazyadapter

I'm trying to populate custom ListView with this [LazyAdapter](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/LazyAdapter.java) class from this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text)

I want to make list view items with custom design. Layout file `list_row.xml` is in my layouts file just like in the tutorial. This is a slightly modified getView function in `LazyAdapter` class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        //vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);    //EDITED
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView subtitle = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.subtitle); // artist name
    //ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

    //This is not needed
    //HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> post;
    post = data.get(position);
    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(post.get("title"));     //the code crashes here
    subtitle.setText(post.get("subtitle"));
    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

Well this code crashes at `title.setText()`, because the title is null. I read somewhere that this makes sense because this LazyAdapter is calling `findViewById` before `setContentView` or something..

So how do I have to do this? And how does this code work for that guy?

**Update**

This is the `list_row.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Subtitle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To save space I'm only adding `ListView` xml from the main activity layout file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/feedListView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/volumeControl1">
</ListView>
```

Adapter code: http://pastebin.com/niC1yXiJ

And the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/myW8B0Xz

Comment: setContentView is used by Activities, and not used in this case. If the inflater is truly inflating a layout with the ids you are referencing, there should not be a null pointer. Could you post the xml that goes along with this? Also, you should be calling inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false); This allows the inflated layout to use the parent's layout but the false keeps it from getting attached. You might also post the error log

Comment: What is data here below the hashmap code line ? If you are getting null at title then there is no value by key title in post hashmap.

Comment: HashMap data gets populated.. that's working ok..

Comment: post stack trace too.

Comment: Ignore Sathish's comment, this isn't a duck typed language. You'd be better off with String.format("%1$s", post.get("title"))

Comment: No. I checked with the debugger: findViewById returns null so title is null. There's no problem with data.

Comment: If findViewById is returning null, then you are loading the wrong xml or have caching issues. Try changing your inflate method like I said in my first comment.

Comment: Have you tried changing the inflate parameters?

Comment: can u post ur whole adapter

Comment: yesterday I gave up.. it was 6 o'clock in the morning.. :| I'm still trying to resolve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a hell of a ride (two sleepless nights). Thanks for all your help, somehow I fixed it! :)

Mostly thanks to this question [Null pointer exception in getView() of custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792133/null-pointer-exception-in-getview-of-custom-adapter) I made new getView function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)activity).getLayoutInflater();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.subtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    HashMap<String, String> post;
    post = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(post.get("title"));
    holder.subtitle.setText(post.get("subtitle"));
    return vi;
}
```

holder is just a simple class:

```
private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView subtitle;
}
```

I've done that and I also copied xml drawable files in all drawable folders (merged all). So one of this actions fixed it, but I'm not quite sure what..

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in the parent when you inflate your cell. Using this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29):

public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
```

Comment: yes. that's exactly what i have now but doesn't solve the problem.. I'll edit the code in the question...

Comment: Can you just for testing purposes remove your hashmap and hardcode in values so I can be sure of what is actually null in this situation, example: title.setText("test");

Comment: I get the same error. This is the new getView function http://pastebin.com/CyDBW7dx and this is the new stack trace: http://pastebin.com/97hCnLQY

Answer (score 0):

If you  get   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1408)  exception than your returned View of getView() is probably null.So check  first of all that you are not return null  view.

Comment: android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1408)  is this exception arise??

Comment: at last line  return vi;  view shuld not null check at that point not at starting point